# text glyph clip angular material font override

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm having trouble with text glyphs getting clipped in angular material input lables. I have a custom font override happening that seems to be the source of the issue (if I set the font back to roboto the font no longer clips).

`$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Open Sans, sans-serif'
);`

For context it was also clipping in the input text fields but I was able to fix that with this rule:

`input.mat-input-element {
  height:100%;
}`

Has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: Tried to replicate this here: https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-material-custom-font-test I don't see any clipping. I even added tachyons expecting that it might be conflicting with material CSS. Do you perhaps have other CSS that could be doing this? Also, where are you loading the font from? Could the font file be corrupted? Have you tried any other fonts?

Comment: @winkerVSbecks  wow thanks for doing a test repo! The font is coming in from google fonts. I've tried linking and importing Open Sans and both have the clipping happening. BUT when I switch to 'Lato' the clip is gone! I wonder if it is a corrupted file?

Comment: @winkerVSbecks also I did reproduce the issue in your example by changing the labels to have j's and g's and they now clip 
  `<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="groovy jazz"> //
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>`

Comment: ok, awesome. That gives me more info to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Open Sans itself, see: https://codepen.io/winkerVSbecks/pen/jZKbze

```
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
height: 18px;
font-size: 16px;   
padding: 0;
```

When input has padding 0 and the difference between height and font-size is less than 4px it seems to clip the text. I have no idea why it does this, but at least we know that this is not an issue caused by ng-material.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming my suspicions! I'm going to just go with a different font at this point. I don't want the client to have future issues even if I manage to hack some solution to this specific one, since it's been problematic in 2 instances already. Thank yoooouuuuu!

Answer (score 0):

I work at Google on the Google Fonts team, and I've filed this at https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1457 to track its resolution